# Hex to String & String to Hex conversion in nodejs

Tags: node.js, string, encoding, buffer

I need to convert data into String to Hex and then again from Hex to String using nodejs 8

I have issue while decoding from Hex to String

**Code to convert `string into hex`**

```
function stringToHex(str)
{
    const buf = Buffer.from(str, 'utf8');
    return buf.toString('hex');
}
```

**Code to convert `hex into string`**

```
function hexToString(str)
{
    const buf = new Buffer(str, 'hex');
    return buf.toString('utf8');
}
```

I have string `dailyfile.host`

output of **encoding**: `3162316637526b62784a5a37697a45796c656d465643747a4a505a6f59774641534c75714733544b4446553d`

output of **decoding**: `1b1f7RkbxJZ7izEylemFVCtzJPZoYwFASLuqG3TKDFU=`

**Required** output of decoding: `dailyfile.host`

Comment: FYI, this is not an encryption, this is an _encoding_.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts for correcting me :)

Comment: Are your sure you use this code ? (And call it right)

I define function same you.

I call this code

`stringToHex('dailyfile.host'); // '6461696c7966696c652e686f7374'` 
` hexToString(stringToHex('dailyfile.host')); // 'dailyfile.host'`

Comment: Voting to close, as [mcve] is not satisfied. Please produce a complete and verifiable example. There is no code here that can reproduce a conversion from `dailyfile.host` to `3162316637526b62784a5a37697a45796c656d465643747a4a505a6f59774641534c75714733544b4446553d`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use `Buffer.from()` for decoding as well. Consider writing a higher-order function to reduce the amount of repeated code:

```
const convert = (from, to) => str => Buffer.from(str, from).toString(to)
const utf8ToHex = convert('utf8', 'hex')
const hexToUtf8 = convert('hex', 'utf8')

hexToUtf8(utf8ToHex('dailyfile.host')) === 'dailyfile.host'
```

Comment: This still does not work for me, I am using `nodejs v8.11`.

Comment: @Hassaan "This does not work" is not a problem statement. Be more specific about the issue you're having.

Comment: Issue is still the same while decoding. Encoded string `4d6a772b646e316c4e314867684c435431724a53674e593430306333675274474753506742672f622b4f6b3d` but decoded string is `Mjw+dn1lN1HghLCT1rJSgNY400c3gRtGGSPgBg/b+Ok=`

Comment: That's because your hexadecimal string _is_ the hex encoding of that output string. What's the output of `utf8ToHex('dailyfile.host')`? It should be `6461696c7966696c652e686f7374`.

Comment: I see, how to resolve it? Can you please update answer for this?

Comment: Where is that "encoded string" coming from? Can you update your question to clarify?

Comment: I am giving string to as parameter of GET request to URL. I am updating my question

Comment: I have tested your provided answer as sandbox. Its working fine but there was issue with my code as you mentioned in above comment. I was using `@skavinvarnan/cryptlib` module for encryption and while while decoding I was not using that module. Thanks man for pointing me in right way :)

Comment: Just check that hex string doesnot start with '0x', and above code should work while converting from hex to utf8

Comment: The way that you answered the question communicated how an entire concept works using 4 lines of code. Its brilliant.  1up  Fantastic answer, this is great man! **Thank sir @PatrickRoberts !**

Comment: I do want to point out that `from` is the name of a parameter, not a keyword. It seems that Stack Overflow is unable to correctly parse & highlight JavaScript.