# Nodejs - webscoket set encoding for receiving data?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a websocket proxy to TCP setup. But the data I receive is HEX buffer. How I can I convert it to string readable format? I think I have to set it to utf-8 but I don't see a option for that in websocket.

Example of data recevied:

```
Received:  <Buffer 3c 63 72 6f 73 73 2d 61 69 6e 272 6f  2a 27 ... 46 more bytes>
```

Client code:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://example.com:1211');

ws.onmessage = message => {
  console.log('Received: ', message.data)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const convert = (from, to) => hexMessage => Buffer.from(hexMessage, from).toString(to);

const hexToUtf8 = convert('hex', 'utf8');

hexToUtf8('your hex msg here')
```

Also check out this post: [Hex to String & String to Hex conversion in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261494/hex-to-string-string-to-hex-conversion-in-nodejs)

Comment: Thanks that worked. I used the Buffer from directly.

`var buf = Buffer.from(message.data); 
console.log(buf.toString());`